# Unit тестирование HttpServletResponse

Tags: java, servlet, junit

помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.
Есть метод, который сохраняет файл и скачивает его(файл Excel) через Servlet соответственно.

Как можно сделать Unit тест, чтобы файл сохранился в папку Download?

Сам код экспорта

```
public void exportFileExcel(HttpServletResponse response, TreeNodeModel treeNodeModel) throws IOException {
    ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
    String fileName = "campaign.xlsx";

    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + fileName);
    response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");

    XSSFWorkbook xssfWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet sheet = xssfWorkbook.createSheet("Campaign");

    Node node = treeNodeModel.getTreeNodeModel();
    if (node != null) {
        int colCell = 0;
        fillNode(sheet, node, colCell);
    }
    xssfWorkbook.write(outputStream);
    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.close();
}
```

Сам тест

```
@Test
public void test() {
    MockHttpServletResponse response = new MockHttpServletResponse();
    try {
        exportToFile.exportFileExcel(response, treeNodeModel);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Ответ просто получаю Ок и все, но хотелось бы сам файл получить. Не могу понять как вытащить данные.

Comment: У Вас написано все в одном месте -> У Вас возникает сложность в тестировании -> Вас должна насторожить сложность в тестировании -> Вы должны подумать о декомпозиции -> Вы должны сделать декомпозицию -> Вы делаете тестирование. У Вас контроллер по сути объединен с сервисом, разнесите их и тестируйте сервис, а контроллер можете дернуть через SOUP UI при интеграционном тестировании.

Comment: @ezhov_da Спасибо, сервис протестировал. Думал, что возможно еще как-то. Ну да ладно, вопрос закрыт